# phpMyAdmin Browse Button Is Gray While Data Exists

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing a strange issue in phpMyAdmin where the Browse Button is gray while data exists in the table, I even tried to run a sql select statement on this table and the records where displayed !

I am using a shared hosting so my options of installing another GUI tool or using the command line are very limited, anyone encountered the same issue before and what is its cause?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot if possible

Comment: I added the screen shot, in the upper one you will find that the browse and empty buttons disabled as if the table is empty while in the bottom ones you will find the sql statement that I ran and the results, plus yesterday it was working fine without issues !